# Reliability of a service

Tags: software-engineering, reliability

Assume that I need to determine the reliability of a service. The service includes component **a** (software reliability=0.95) and component **b** (software reliability=0.98). I have 2 computers: Computer **A** (hardware reliability=0.99) and Computer **B** (hardware reliability=0.99).

I have two following cases:

> Case 1: Deploy both **a** and **b** on computer **A**. For this case, the service
> reliability is around **0.923**.
>
> Case 2: Deploy **a** on computer **A**, and **b** on computer **B**. For this case, the service reliability is around **0.912**

I really wonder why the service reliability in case 2 is lower than in case 1. The thing is **A** and **B** have the same hardware reliability. Can someone clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case 1, for the service to not fail we need three things to not fail: computer **A**, component **a** and component **b**. In contrast, in Case 2 we also need computer **B** to not fail. Plainly the probability in the latter case is smaller, by a factor of 0.99.

You can calculate the non-failure probability by just multiplying the non-failure probabilities for the relevant objects:

- Case 1: $0.99 \cdot 0.98 \cdot 0.95 = 0.92169$.
- Case 2: $0.99 \cdot 0.99 \cdot 0.98 \cdot 0.95 = 0.9124731$.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the software reliability for now, and only focus on the machines.

In case 1 there is only one machine that can fail, and it fails 1% of the time.

In case 2 there are *two* machines that can fail. However, even if just one fails the service goes down. The chance that at least one machine fails is $1 - 0.99^2 = 1.99\%$. So instead of spreading the risk we've just made our service more liable to fail.

There are two components to making a system reliable despite hardware failure:

1. Spreading out risk of failure across multiple machines.
2. Making the system robust to failure of some machines.

In the exercise we do have #1 but are missing #2.

Comment: Thank for nice explanation. If I have choice to approve your answer as well, I surely will do that.